# Angular $scope not getting variables

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have a simple html file that make make search on Algolia and returns result. I can console the result but can not access $scope.users from view.  How can I grab that $scope.users in view.

here is my app.js file

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('usersController', function($scope) {
        $scope.users = [];

        var client = algoliasearch('my_app_id', 'my_app_key');
        var index = client.initIndex('getstarted_actors');

        index.search('john', function searchDone(err, content) {
          $scope.users.push(content.hits);
          console.log(content.hits);
        });

    });
```

Here is my html view file

```
<div class="results" ng-controller="usersController">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
    </div>  
</div>
```

note: ng-app="myApp" attribute given in html tag.

Comment: what does {{user}} print, I believe you don't have the name property on the user.

Comment: Sintax looks old, try *ng-controller="usersController as user"* then *ng-repeat="usr in user.users"* and *{{usr.name}}* , OBVIOUSLY be sure your $scope.users.push() is really pushing

Comment: I think  $scope.users.push() its not really pushing. because when i console  $scope.users outside of index.search function() its just consoling empty [] array. What should I do? @sbaaang?

Answer (score 1):

It's *most likely* because your `index.search` call isn't triggering an Angular `$digest` cycle - manually trigger one with either `$apply` or a `$timeout`

```
index.search('john', function searchDone(err, content) {
  $scope.users.push(content.hits);
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

The `$apply()` could throw `$digest already in progress` errors - another way with a `$timeout`

```
myApp.controller('usersController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    index.search('john', function searchDone(err, content) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.users.push(content.hits);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$scope.$evalAsync()` i would say :P instead of $timeout

Comment: no need for the `$timeout` as it wraps a call to `$apply` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout which can be turned off by setting `invokeApply` to false (defaults to true)

Comment: I think $scope.users.push() its not really pushing. because when i console $scope.users outside of index.search function() its just consoling empty [] array. What should I do?

Comment: @MohammadOhidul -- Did you try the above solution? The log could be wrong since the above search is async...

Answer (score 0):

try calling `$scope.$apply()` to update your bindings

```
index.search('john', function searchDone(err, content) {
  $scope.users.push(content.hits);
  console.log(content.hits);
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`algoliasearch` doesn't look like it's an injected service and therefore not native to the angular framework.  Try calling `$scope.$apply()`.